# Content type from Content Hub not updated

Tags: content-type

I have a content hub with a content type based on a Document Set.

If I remove a column or make a change to an existing column from the hub content type and then on CA I run the Content Type Hub job and Content Type Subscriber job, I don't see the changes published.

- content type syndication hub is enabled on my site content hub site collection
- Refresh all published content types on next update is checked in my subscriber site collection
- no error in shown in Content type hub error publishing log

Is there anything else I should check?

Comment: Upto my knowledge you have run the timer jobs required. But I dont understand why it happens so. There were many weird issues like this while using Content type hub. May be this would be one among it.

Comment: Look in ULS-Log while content types are getting published. You may find an helpful error message there.

Comment: I see that refresh check box. Do you have to manually hit refresh each time there is an update to the content type?

Answer (score 0):

May be you might have to check this,

1. Go to `your subscribed site > site settings > content type
   publishing`
2. Under site collection administration, make sure you have checked 
   "refresh all published content types on next update”

This will update all published content types the next time the content type subscriber timer job runs.

Comment: Check my post. This was already done. Thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry i didnt see that. Then as i said before it should be some weird issue. Give some time and run nthe timers again. No other way.