# Is my content type local or inherits from Hub Content Type?

Tags: content-type, content-type-hub

As I am experience some problems with updating a content type that should
inherit from a content hub (
[my previous post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184241/content-type-from-content-hub-not-updated/184242?noredirect=1#comment193095_184242) )
, I want to know if I could see if a content type is local or inherits from my
content hub.

I see in the hub content type that it is possible to cancel the publication. 
Doing so, according to what I read, all subscriber content types
become local.

So, could I check somewhere if my content type is local?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is even an easy way to do that but here is what I just figured out looking through all the properties of my Content Types.

When a Content Type is inherited from a Content Type Hub then the property *SchemaXmlWithResourceTokens* looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentType ID="0x010100EED4D9C563FDC1408AC154B300E928EE" Name="aaa" Group="Custom Content Types" ReadOnly="TRUE" Version="9">
    <Folder TargetName="_cts/aaa" />
    <FieldRefs>
        ...
        ...
    </FieldRefs>
    <DocumentTemplate TargetName="" />
    <XmlDocuments>
        <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ContentTypeSync">
        ...
        </XmlDocument>
        <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
        ...
        </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
</ContentType>
```

The important thing here is the line:

```
<XmlDocument NamespaceURI="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ContentTypeSync">
```

That seems to indicate that the Content Type is coming from the Hub.

Comment: Sorry, but where do I check the content type xml? I cannot seem to find it in Sharepoint Designer.

Comment: I use this tool to look through the properties: [SPCB](https://spcb.codeplex.com/)